# How to copy only non-provided dependencies when several are provided?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, dependency-management

In our project setup we have at runtime a spring boot app where we add other jars to it via the `loader.path` mechanism of the [PropertiesLauncher](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-executable-jar-format.html#executable-jar-property-launcher-features). Those jars are all located in a `lib` folder beside the actual spring boot app. In development the spring boot app itself is provided to us and we only develop the additional jars.

So we have a lot of dependencies that are provided via the spring-boot app like `spring-context` etc. But for example in one jar we depend on `spring-webflux`, which is not provided in the spring-boot app itself. But some of the dependencies of `spring-webflux` are already provided. So we only want to copy those dependencies of `spring-webflux` that are not provided by the spring-boot app, to not have jars in our `lib` folder that are already packaged in the spring-boot app.

To put it more general: How do I copy dependencies of artifact A excluding all those that artifact B depends on?

I tried it using:

```
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies-to-lib</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                            <excludeScope>provided</excludeScope>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

The spring-boot is declared as a `provided` dependency and the additional jars are declared as `runtime` dependencies.

A complete minimal example is this:

`./pom.xml:`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>a</module>
        <module>b</module>
        <module>c</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

`./a/pom.xml:`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>a</artifactId>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

`./b/pom.xml:`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>b</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

`./c/pom.xml:`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>c</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>a</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>b</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies-to-lib</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                            <excludeScope>provided</excludeScope>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

In the above example my expectation is that `./c/target/lib` only contains `b-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` and `commons-lang-2.6.jar` since `commons-io` is provided by module `a`. But the directory still contains `commons-io`.

Comment: `commons-io` is also a runtime dependency for module `b` that is why it is included.
As a naive solution to your initial question you can manually exclude those dependencies of `weblux` that are provided to you using Maven exclusions function for dependencies

Comment: @Ivan excluding dependenies manually is what we do currently as a workaround. But this is challenging since dependencies may change at every release and hence it has a high maintenance effort.

Comment: Two suggestions: If you _really_ want the solution for your general question, I guess you need to write your own Maven plugin. You could craft it to copy exactly the artifacts you want. If you don't want to dig so deep, you could think about building a BOM where you manage all relevant artifacts to `provided`.

Comment: @JFMeier Can you explain how a BOM would help here? In fact the artifacts provided by the spring-boot app are managed in a bom. But I don't see how I can say "copy all dependencies excluding those specified in this bom".

Comment: You can use a BOM to make sure that all dependencies in the BOM are actually `provided` and that scope is not overridden by other dependencies in your project. This might make it more robust to filter by scope.